# viewWillAppear woes

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults

I'm using `NSUserDefaults` to keep an object in sync across several `UIViewController`s that are used in a `UITabbarController`. To do this, I'm implementing the following

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"ViewControllerX Will Appear");
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"sharedDictionary"];
    [customObject setDictionary:dict];
}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"ViewControllerX Will Disappear");
    NSDictionary *dict = [customObject dictionary];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dict forKey:@"sharedDictionary"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

Here `customObject` is an instance of a custom class that has a property `dictionary` of type `NSDictionary`. This object may get changed by the visible `UIViewController`.

The problem I current have is that when the user switches tabs, say from `ViewControllerX` to `ViewControllerY`, these methods aren't getting called in the expected order. I expect to see this in the log:

```
ViewControllerX Will Disappear
ViewControllerY Will Appear
```

but instead I see

```
ViewControllerY Will Appear
ViewControllerX Will Disappear
```

The result is that the old dictionary is loaded in `ViewControllerY`, and only after switching tabs again does the new dictionary appear. Is there an easy way around this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no guarantee which order these methods are going to be called in, so you can't rely on any ordering with them. The only guarantee you get is that `-viewWillAppear:` and `-viewWillDisappear:` will be called before the view appears or disappears respectively.

Another way to deal with this might be changing this to a will/did type scenario. So, you save the current state of your object in `-viewWillDisappear:` and you restore the state (i.e., load your dictionary) in `-viewDidAppear:`. This will guarantee that the view that is going away saves its dictionary before the view that appears.

Another approach would be to change the way the custom dictionary is passed between your view controllers and use a delegate object on your application's `UITabBarViewController` to deal with syncing these changes to the user defaults. You can integrate this into your app however makes the most sense, but I'll provide a basic example below along with the changes you'd need to provide to your app (as described in your question):

To use the example, you need to make these changes (adapt to your coding style):

- add an `NSDictionary` to ivar named `_sharedDictionary` to your application delegate
- load the dictionary from the user defaults when the app launches
- declare that your app delegate implements the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol
- when your app loads, assign your app delegate as the delegate of your main `UITabBarController`.
- change your view controllers to respond to a new property which you can call `sharedDictionary`
- you can maintain the rest of your code where in `-viewWillAppear` you set the value of the view controller's `sharedDictionary` property to your custom object and just continue as you did before

After you've done those things, add the following method implementation to your app delegate:

```
-(BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController*)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController*)viewController
{
  // If you're using ARC, you can remove the retain/autorelease statements
  [_sharedDictionary autorelease];

  // In order to avoid a compiler warning here, you should have your view controllers
  // possibly inherit from a parent that defines the sharedDictionary property and cast
  // to that, or have your view controllers implement a protocol that defines the
  // property, and cast to that. As long as your view controllers actually implement
  // the sharedDictionary property, however, everything will work
  _sharedDictionary = [[[tabBarController selectedViewController] sharedDictionary] retain];

  // set the shared dictionary on the new view controller -- same casting rules apply
  // as stated above
  [viewController setSharedDictionary:_sharedDictionary];

  // save this to user defaults so that if the app stops, it maintains whatever state
  // you're keeping
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:_sharedDictionary forKey:@"sharedDictionary"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
  });

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem but creates a new one in the form of a lag when switching views. That's a lesser problem, though, so definitely helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @user1177016 The best way to deal with that is to write the views so that they can display something meaningful before they finish retrieving your object and then update the display gracefully. If that's possible, you can use *GCD* dispatch off the save and read and the UI will appear more responsive. Another approach would be to use the UITabBarController delegate and do this there (I'll update my answer with an example of that)

Comment: They start with the old dictionary, then update it once the view appears. This isn't bad, but it isn't perfect either. There is a visible transition that I was hoping to avoid, but since it takes a small fraction of a second, I can live with it. I've gone through and implemented your suggestion, and I think I'll proceed with this until I learn enough about what the other two people are saying to find a (possibly) better way. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. Instead of each view controller having their own copy of CustomObject and trying to keep them in sync via NSUserDefaults, have both view controllers share the same instance of CustomObject.

In addition, you might also try using the [Observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) design pattern. Your view controllers would play the role of Observer, and a single CustomObject instance would play the role of Subject.

---

The details on saving/loading `customObject`'s state to/from user defaults should be encapsulated inside `customObject` and hidden from your view controllers. Your view controllers should not need to know *how* `customObject` save/loads a `NSDictionnary` to/from user defaults. Your `customObject`'s class should look something like this:

```
@interface CustomClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, assign) float value;

- (void)save;
- (void)load;
// Other methods

@end


@implementation CustomClass

@synthesize name = name_;
@synthesize value = value_;

- (void)save
{
    NSDictionary* dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          name_, @"Name",
                          [NSNumber numberWithFloat:value_], @"Value",
                          nil];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dict
                                              forKey:@"CustomObject"];
}

- (void)load
{
    NSDictionary* dict = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]
                          objectForKey:@"CustomObject"];
    name_ = [dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
    NSNumber* valueNum = [dict objectForKey:@"Value"];
    value_ = [valueNum floatValue];
}

@end
```

Your `customObject` should be loaded once when your application starts. One place you can do this is in your AppDelegate's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
        didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [sharedCustomObject load];
}
```

In your view controllers' `viewWillAppear`, you don't need to make `sharedCustomObject` reload itself. **It will already hold the current state**.

In your view controllers' `viewWillDisappear`, you only need to make sure that `sharedCustomObject`'s state is **backed-up** in the user defaults.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [sharedCustomObject save];
}
```

After saving, `sharedCustomObject` **is still up-to-date and does not need to be reloaded**.

I hope things are clearer now. :-)

Comment: This is what I'm doing, but the same problem persists.

Comment: Then you don't need to reload `customObject` from the user defaults every time you switch tabs, because `customObject` already holds the current state. You just need to save `customObject` to the user defaults when leaving a view. The only time you need to load `customObject` from user defaults would be when your app starts.

Comment: @user1177016 Can you expand on the problem? If the view controllers are sharing the same instance of CustomObject, then they can't possibly be out of sync because there's only one. Have the controllers use KVO to observe that object as Emile suggests so that they notice when the data changes and can take appropriate action.

Comment: The customObject changes the contents of the dictionary as things happen in the viewcontroller. So when the view appears, the dictionary is loaded. Things happen. When the dictionary is saved as the view disappears, it is potentially a different dictionary. The custom object has methods and other things associated with it to change the dictionary. From the documentation, I thought I could not save customObject using NSUserDefaults, which is why I only saved the common bits into an NSDictionary.

Comment: @user1177016: There is nothing wrong with that approach for saving/loading customObject. What bothers me is that you needlessly reload customObject when it is already up-to-date.

Comment: Huh? It isn't up to date. That's my whole problem. When VCX changes the dictionary, VCY doesn't find out about it until after it has appeared, thereby causing the problem.

Comment: VCX and VCY shouldn't even care about the dictionary, it is a design detail that should be encapsulated inside customObject. I will post some code to make things clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use `NSUserDefaults` in that way, probably. You should be able to encapsulate behaviour in a given view controller and not rely on a particular execution path to manipulate shared state. Either use Jason's suggestion of `viewDidAppear` or pass `ViewControllerX`'s internal copy of the dictionary straight into `ViewControllerY` to avoid having to work around it.

Comment: How do I do that? I don't know how to access the properties of `ViewControllerY` from within `ViewContollerX`.

Comment: How are you getting from `ViewControllerX` to `ViewControllerY`? At some point, it has to be created. You're switching tabs, so you'll need to override your tab bar controller delegate's `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` function and call `setCustomObject:` to pass in `customObject` (your current internal copy). Maybe, since this is shared at the top level, you should store it in your application delegate class as a property. That way all of the top-level views can already access it from `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] customObject]` and don't need internal copies.

Comment: As I stated in my post, I'm using a `UITabbarController` in the app. Views are changed by selecting tabs.

Comment: You should be able to use the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` method `- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to those methods. I'll look through the documentation to see if I can find a more elegant solution. Thanks again.